# Enum to int best practice

Tags: c#, enums

I can't select between two methods of converting. What is the best practice by converting from enum to int

1:

```
public static int EnumToInt(Enum enumValue)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(enumValue);
}
```

2:

```
public static int EnumToInt(Enum enumValue)
{
    return (int)(ValueType)enumValue;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to @dtb

You can specify the int (or flag) of your enum by supplying it after the equals sign.

```
enum MyEnum
{
    Foo = 0,
    Bar = 100,
    Baz = 9999
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

If you have an enum  such as

```
enum MyEnum
{
    Foo,
    Bar,
    Baz,
}
```

and a value of that enum such as

```
MyEnum value = MyEnum.Foo;
```

then the best way to convert the value to an `int` is

```
int result = (int)value;
```

Answer (score 3):

I would throw a third alternative into the mix in the form of an extension method on Enum

```
public static int ToInt(this Enum e)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(e);
}

enum SomeEnum
{
    Val1 = 1,
    Val2 = 2,
    Val3 = 3,
}

int intVal = SomeEnum.ToInt();
```